# Describing closure and interior in Moore Plane

Tags: general-topology, moore-plane

I'm trying the following exercise from Willard's General Topology. Please verify what I did and help me at item 3.

**4B** Let $\Gamma$ denote the closed upper half plane $\{(x,y)|y \geq 0\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. For each point in the open upper half-plane, basic nhoods will be the usual open disks (with the restriction, of course, that they be taken small enough to lie in $\Gamma$). At the points $z$ on the x-axis, the basic nhoods will be the sets $\{z\}\cup A$, where $A$ is an open disk in the upper half plane, tangent to the x-axis at $z$.

1. Verify that this gives a topology on $\Gamma$.
2. Compare the topology thus obtained with the usual topology on the closed upper half plane as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.
3. Describe the closure and interior operations in the space $\Gamma$.

This is my attemt at 1 and 2:

1) 
If $p \in \{(x,y)| y>0\}$, basic nhoods of $p$ are usual balls $B(y,\epsilon)$, for a small enough $\epsilon$. If $z \in \{(x,0)| x \in \mathbb{R}$, basic nhoods of $z$ are sets $\{z\}\cup A$, where $A$ is open disk tangent to x-axis. Let $B_x$ the nhood basis of $x \in \Gamma$.

I'll use theorem 4.5:
Let $x \in \Gamma$.

V-a)  Let $V \in B_x$. Or $V = B(x,\epsilon)$ or $V=\{x\} \cup A$, so either way $x \in V$.

V-b) Let $V_1,V_2 \in B_x$. Case 1) $x$ in x axis. Then $V_1,V_2$ are tangent to x axis, then one is contained on the other, wlg $V_1 \subseteq V_2$. Let $V_3 = V_1$, then $V_3 \in B_x$ and $V_3 \subseteq V_1 \cap V_2$. Case 2) $x$ in $\Gamma$ but not in x axis. Then $V_1 = B(x, \epsilon_1), V_2 = B(x, \epsilon_2)$, wlg $V_1 \subseteq V_2$. Let $V_3=V1$, then $V_3 \in B_x$ and $V_3 \subseteq V_1 \cap V_2$;

V-c) Let $V \in B_x$. Case 1) $x$ in x axis. $V$ is tangent to x axis. Let $V_0 = V$. If $y=x$, make $W=V$. If not, there is $B(y,\epsilon) \subseteq V$. Make $W=B(y,\epsilon)$. Case 2) $x$ in $\Gamma$ but not in x-axis. $V=B(x,\epsilon)$. Make $V=V_0$. $V$ is open, then $\forall y \in V_0 \exists B(y,\delta) \subseteq V$. Make $W=B(y,\delta)$.

Then, define $G \subseteq_{\rm{open}} \Gamma \iff \exists B \subseteq G | B \in B_x \forall x \in G$. 
By theorem 4.5, this defines a topology.

2) It is stronger than the usual topology, because it contains all the open sets $B(x,\epsilon)$ and those of the form $\{x\} \cup A$, which are not open in the usual.

3) This is where I need help the most. I tried defining closure and interior by this theorem 4.7:

$E^O = \{ x \in \Gamma | \text{some basic nhood of x is contained in E}\}$

$\bar{E} = \{ x \in \Gamma | \text{each basic nhood of x meets in E}\}$

I don't know how to describe these interior and closure for every set, specially for those that have points in x axis. I think those that don't have points in x axis have usual closure and interior as in usual topology. Also 
there is a lot of exercises like this in Willard:"describe closure and interior". What is the best approach for this kind of exercise?

Comment: Any help in understanding what he meant by "describe" interior and closure would be appreciated...

Comment: He wanst a "recipe" for finding the closure of a set or the interior, in this case in terms of the usual topology on the half plane, e.g.

Comment: Note that e.g. all subsets of the $x$-axis are closed in the Moore plane. And the usual interior of $A \cap H$ is a subset of the interior of $A$, if $H = \{(x,y): y > 0\}$.